# How to submit an iOS Watch app / iOS app without going through TestFlight?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, ios-app-extension, apple-watch

How can I submit an iOS app without going through TestFlight?

The iOS app has a Watch Extension + Watch App going with it. TestFlight just gave me an error twice in iTunes Connect that "TestFlight doesn't support apps with WatchKit extension." So, I have to submit it without going through TestFlight.

**UPDATE**: The builds with the watch extension/app are now going through Testflight successfully. Apple must have just flipped the switch to allow them for everyone. (Friday, April 24, 2015; 1:12 CST)

Comment: Yes you cannot test your app using testflight if it has a watch app too. All you can do at this time is upload and submit for review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message isn't entirely clear. TestFlight doesn't support WatchKit for beta testing. Despite the error message you can still submit your app just fine. I've done it for a number of apps.

Comment: You nailed it. As you said, that error message isn't entirely clear. I just needed to get into the "Versions" part of the iTunes web app and submit the app like I used to before TestFlight was integrated by apple.